# What site to use for career recommendations?

Tags: support, jobs, site-recommendation

I'm looking for advice regarding what kind of professional career to pursue if you have / like several determined skills. In my particular case skills that belong to DSP, Electrical and StackOverflow sites. Where should I post this kind of questions? Is there a specific community for career advice or I should use any of the mentioned sites?

Answer (score 7):

> Where should I post this kind of questions? Is there a specific community for career advice or I should use any of the mentioned sites?

I am afraid there's no site within the SE Network that would consider those types of questions on-topic.<sup>1</sup> Because:

1. They are primarily *opinion based*
2. Questions like that would attract a lot of unwanted spam.

The closest you can get, IMO, is

- [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/)

But that site is more about particular problems at the workplace, rather than general career advice based on particular skills.

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>Some sites like e.g. SE Software engineering explicitly deny such questions as *off-topic*.</sub>